# Regex Capture Group Not Appearing

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to do some regex work on the following (this is an example of what I am working on)

- `.4 YD CRANE LIFT FEL`
- `1-96 Gallon Dragon Flame RCY`
- `1-96 Gl  volcanoes rus FEL 2x Wk`

Code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(stff)
df = df['Service Description']
descriptions = df.to_string().split('\n')
m = re.search('(?<=abc)def', 'abcdef')
m = re.search(r'([0-9,\-,.,]*)?\s?([A-z]*)\b\s*(((?!FEL|REL|S\/L|RCY)[A-z]*\s)*)*\s?(FEL|REL|S\/L]*)?\s?(RCY|RECY*)?\s?([1-7,x,X]{2,4})?\s?([W,w,k,K,m,o,M,O]{2}|EOW)?', descriptions[1])
print(m.groups())
```

I got the regex working on https://regexr.com/ but when I put it into python I get all the groups except group(3) which counts as blank for some reason.

I am sure there is some problems with the regex (aka better ways to do what I am) but I am not concerned with those at the moment and request you shelve such comments unless they solve the issue.

The print out gives me this
('.4', 'YD', '', 'LIFT ', 'FEL', None, None, None)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually capturing the data you want. Your third "capture group" looks something like `(...)*`, and the parentheses just serve to group the underlying expression. You probably want something more like `((...)*)` to capture everything. In your case that looks like this:

```
([0-9,\-,.,]*)?\s?([A-z]*)\b\s*((((?!FEL|REL|S\/L|RCY)[A-z]*\s)*)*)\s?(FEL|REL|S\/L]*)?\s?(RCY|RECY*)?\s?([1-7,x,X]{2,4})?\s?([W,w,k,K,m,o,M,O]{2}|EOW)?
```